# Animation from the tap position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could you please help me to figure out what's wrong with my attempts to create an animation of blood on the tap on the character's head? The problem is that this blood just don't appear at all.

[image: PICTURE]

On the picture you can see that I've added 2 scripts to the character's head and added BloodSprayEffect from EffectExamples.
Here are those scripts:

## BloodOnTap.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BloodOnTap : MonoBehaviour {

    private static BloodOnTap instance;

    public ParticleSystem bloodEffect;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }


    void Start ()
    {
        if (bloodEffect == null)
            Debug.LogError("Missing Blood Effect");
    }

    public static ParticleSystem MakeBlood(Vector3 position)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("There is no SpecialEffect in the scene!");
            return null;
        }
        ParticleSystem effect = Instantiate(instance.bloodEffect) as ParticleSystem;
        effect.transform.position = position;

        Destroy(effect.gameObject, effect.duration);
        return effect;
    }
}
```

## BloodOnTapTouch.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BloodOnTapTouch : MonoBehaviour {


    void Update ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touch.tapCount == 1)
            {
                Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

                BloodOnTap.MakeBlood((position));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the code from http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/unity-touch-controls/.

Comment: I would try to determine if a.- the blood is being activated but for some reason we cannot see it (like, maybe the position is wrong/too far, maybe the camera is not rendering the layer where the blood is defined, maybe the object's scale is too small, etc...) or b.- The blood is not being activated at all.| Are you testing on a device? `Input.GetTouch` doesn't consider mouse input, so if you are on the editor and 'click' instead of 'touch' the code `Vector3 position... ; BloodOnTap.MakeBlood` it will never be called.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Do you know why the blood on the device might not look like the the blood animation in Unity?

Comment: In general the particles/effects on the device should reflect what you are seeing on Unity. sometimes different screen resolutions and screen ratios can affect how or where some elements are displayed. but I think that you should not have that problem with the blood particles. You can try adjusting your code to accept mouse events and see what happens! (also you can check if the effect duration is a reasonable number [because the particle instance it will be destroyed after that amount of time] )